# Spread across or spreads across

Tags: verbs

> The estimated cost of PM's new sprawling house 'spread across' 3600 square feet is 10 million.

Is it okay to use 'spreads across' in this sentence?

Comment: 'Spread' is correct here, but the sentence could benefit from a pair of commas to set off the parenthetical: *sprawling new house, spread across 3600 square feet, is 10...*

Comment: Could you please explain it further? Thanks

Comment: You have cross posted this. That is not allowed. sprawling and spread across as I already explained in ELL is not good. Now, however, you have changed the sentence, to try and make it work. Good writing would dictate: **The estimated cost of *PM's new, sprawling 3,600-sq.ft.  house* is 10 million**. No, spreads across is not ok in your sentence.

Comment: Talking about the house "spreading across" 3,600 square feet implies that it's occupying that much land. If you are referring to the total square footage of floor space (which is potentially on multiple levels), then this is the wrong verb to use.

Answer (score 2):

The main structure of the sentence is, “The cost is 10 million,” but there are two noun phrases, either or both of which might be subject(s) of the two verbs: “the estimated cost” and “the new house” for “to spread” and “to be.” Which of the noun phrases is involved in the spreading? Is the house spatially spreading? Or maybe the cost is being spread (amortized)? Your word order suggests that it’s the house that spreads; that and its description as sprawling. Then “spread across 3600 square feet” is a subordinate clause meant to elaborate on the house’s sprawl. That’s the reading on which *spread* is correct. It’s the past participle, and thus analogous to “a cherry **dipped** in chocolate.” As others have said, if you wanted to use *spreads*, you’d have to say, “…house, **which** spreads across 3600 square feet, is…”

Comment: "which spreads across 3,600 feet" would be edited out by any good editor. The only sensible solution would be something like: His new, sprawling 3,600 sq. ft. home, and forget spread..

Comment: I agree that it lacks concision and that an editor could improve it as suggested. I was answering not about its style but only about its grammaticality.

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand your answer. The problem is more semantics than grammar. sprawl and spread work different ways.

Comment: Umm, OK. What don’t you understand about my answer? Is it appropriate to discuss your misunderstanding here? The OP provides an example using “spread across,” and then asks about using “spread**s** across. I—and apparently several others—interpreted OP to be asking about forms of the verb “to spread,” thus a syntactic question rather than a semantic one.

Comment: I think if I use verb 'cover' instead of 'spread' it would be much better.

Comment: So, @Rocky, there’s been some disagreement or misunderstanding about what you were actually asking. Was it whether the verb “to spread,” in any form, would be appropriate in this context, or was it whether the particular form *spread**s*** would be appropriate?  You may observe from the thread above that both notions have been treated by various respondents.

Comment: Sprawling (adj) and spreading creating much confusion here. That's why I am saying this

Comment: I thought why 'spread' is used as a present participle without 's' but your example of cherry dipped in chocolate clears my doubt

Comment: @Lambie: sprawl and spread don't go well together I think.

Comment: @Rocky I suggest you look at the bolded text in my comment under your question.

Comment: @Lambie Yes it is completely fine.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum if "spread across 3600 square feet" is a subordinate clause then this sentence would be fine : "The dignity of PM's house depend on his virtue" where 'depend on his virtue' is acting as a subordinate clause.

Comment: No, that sentence is not well formed. If I understand the meaning you intend by it, the subject of the verb “to depend” is the noun phrase “the PM’s house.” So the verb must agree in number with the (singular) noun *house*. Thus, “The dignity of (the!) PM’s house depend**s** on his virtue.”  Note too that this is a simple sentence consisting of a single clause; it has a structure entirely analogous to that of, say, “My mother’s clock stands on her mantle.”  A subordinate clause might make a sentence like, “The dignity of the PM’s house, **maligned by his critics**, depends on his virtue.”